# How to use a slide toggle in a mat-table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I have a `mat-table` that is viewed by 3 users of different roles.
The table has multiple columns; one of the columns is `active` (a boolean value that controls the activation and deactivation of the account). I want to toggle that value with a switch within the same table (in another column), but only if the user is an admin.

I already achieved this using bootstrap table this way:

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngIf="isAdmin(currentUser)" (click)="sortByAccountStatus()">
                <a>Deactivate/Activate</a>
                <a class="sort-by"></a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let chartOfAccounts of accountList.reverse();" [hidden]="currentUser.role !== '1'">
            <td [hidden]="!chartOfAccounts.accountActive">
                <a (click)="deactivateAccount(chartOfAccounts)" class="text-danger">Deactivate</a>
            </td>
            <td [hidden]="chartOfAccounts.accountActive">
                <a (click)="activateAccount(chartOfAccounts)" class="text-danger">Activate</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let chartOfAccounts of accountList" [hidden]="currentUser.role === '1'">
            <td>{{accountActiveStatus(chartOfAccounts.accountActive)}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The code above will add a column to the table where the admin can click on activate or deactivate depending on the value of the boolean. The operations are implemented in the component.

Using `mat-table`, I got the boolean `active` column to work.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="accountActive">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Active</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let chartOfAccounts"> {{chartOfAccounts.accountActive}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

My goal is to create another column that holds the switch back and forth from `true` to `false` like this

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="activation">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Activate/Deactivate</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let chartOfAccounts" [hidden]="!chartOfAccounts.accountActive">
        <a (click)="deactivateAccount(chartOfAccounts)" class="text-danger">Deactivate</a>
    </mat-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let chartOfAccounts" [hidden]="chartOfAccounts.accountActive">
          <a (click)="activateAccount(chartOfAccounts)" class="text-danger">Deactivate</a>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

This is not working and produces a weird result where when the toggle is switched off it cannot be switched back on again, the link disappears, and the toggle column too. Here is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

The boolean values are pushed to the right of the tables whenever they're switched to `false`

### Updated:

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixibfa?embed=1&file=src/app/table-basic-example.html) example. The toggle does not work but basically when you click on toggle the value of active should switch between `true` and `false` depending on if the toggle is on or off.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz for the same?

Comment: The screenshot doesn't seem consistent with your code. Your code shows that the header's name is `Activate/Deactivate` while the screenshot shows `toggle`

Comment: If you want not show a column you only need change the array `displayedColumns` -the variable you use in the tags `<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>` and 
  `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>`

Comment: @Eliseo thank you eliseo i though i can use [hidden] on the mat-cell, but you response make total sense, tried it and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is that you can't use two `mat-cell` in a `mat-column`. The second one will be ignored completely. This is why your table gets all messed up because on some cells the `hidden` is hiding the only `cell` present in that column (since the second cell is out of the picture).

You shouldn't be using two separate cells for this. You want `Activate`/`Deactivate` to appear in the same cell. So instead of using `hidden` on the `mat-cell`, use `ngIf` on the anchor tags to conditionally show `Activate`/`Deactivate`.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="activation">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Activate/Deactivate</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let chartOfAccounts">
        <a *ngIf="chartOfAccounts.accountActive" (click)="deactivateAccount(chartOfAccounts)" class="text-danger">Deactivate</a>
        <a *ngIf="!chartOfAccounts.accountActive" (click)="activateAccount(chartOfAccounts)" class="text-danger">Activate</a>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**Edit**: (after comments)

If you don't want to show a particular column, just remove it from the displayed columns, this way it won't be rendered by `mat-table`.

```js
allColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'activate', 'toggle'];

checkIfAdmin() {
    this.displayedColumns = this.isAdmin ? this.allColumns : this.allColumns.filter(column => column !== 'toggle');
}
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-toggle).

Comment: one question though, can i add a directive to the ng-container, so that if the user is not and admin than the column should not be displayed  `*<ng-container matColumnDef="activation" *ngIf="isAdmin(currentUser)"`>  normally the ngIf should be on the header so but i dont know if that will work too

Comment: @capuche I have updated my answer and added a working example. Use the `Toggle Admin` button in the example to check what an admin sees and otherwise

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding your button/link is dependent on the value of active or inactive. So you can put 2 anchor tags in a cell and display it based on the value of active column

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="toggle">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Toggle </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <a *ngIf="element.active === false" (click)="toggle(element.position)">Activate</a>
      <a *ngIf="element.active === true" (click)="toggle(element.position)">Deactivate</a>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

As you can see onclick is handled by a single function where I am passing an ID value (unique identifier of that row) and changing the active value on its click

```
toggle(position) {
    this.dataSource.find( d=> d.position === position).active = !this.dataSource.find( d=> d.position === position).active;
  }
```

Working Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ne15tp

**Note:** Please feel free to improve the performance of the code as this is just a dummy implementation for demo purpose

Comment: one more think, since this is viewed by users with different roles and only the admin can perform this action, where would you add the check to say `[hidden]="currentUser.role === '1'"` or `*ngIf="isAdmin(currentUser)"` this seems to work for admin but then when i log in as a regular user its not hidden

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz accordingly. Please check it. If it solves your problem mark it as answer. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
     <mat-slide-toggle
          [matTooltip]="row.active? 'Deactivate': 'Activate'"
          [checked]="row.ativo"
          (change)="updateStatusAccount(row.id, $event)">
      </mat-slide-toggle>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).